# Visual studio locals vanish when using reflection

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have been working on a project and randomly now the locals just vanished stopped showing the box was there but there are no locals in there

So I thought maybe just an error somewhere rebooted computer cleaned solution rebuilt still nothing so I decided to install VS 2017 RC and still nothing so I then went on to see where the locals stop working as they work at the very start but it seems that the locals break after using this line of

```
Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
```

After the debugger has gone over this line the locals for the rest of the projects are gone is there any way to fix this?